# Displaying specific url text when opening new window in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an interesting situation.  I have an application that opens up a new window/tab when a button is clicked.  When it opens, a pre-made html page is displayed to the user and a specific url is set.  My question is, how do I set the url of the window?  I don't want the window to link to another page or site, just display the url I tell it to.  Is this even possible?

Here's what I have so far:

**JS**

```
getSingleResults(screening){
    let url = this.router.url;
    if(screening.isTrue){
        url += "/urlIWantToDisplay";
    }
    this.patientService.getPatientResults(screening.id).subscribe(result => {
        let newWindow = window.open(url).document.write(result);
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="in-line btn" (click)="getSingleResults(screening)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
```

However, in the address bar, I'm still seeing about:blank instead of the url I want to display.

Comment: What's missing? What's not working?

Comment: @enapupe sorry, forgot to add that, I've updated it to explain what's not happening.

Comment: Maybe you want `"about:blank"` ?? Really not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you can't do that.. because it would be a huge security flaw.. Can you imagine changing the URL bar to facebook.com but having control over its content? That's never gonna happen.
If you ever manage to do something like that you can get your prize at https://www.google.com/about/appsecurity/chrome-rewards/